# Semaphore WaitOne not operating correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have a Semaphore that suspose to limit to 3, however, this just keeps calling as many as it wants.  I'm assuming it's because I use (1000).  However, when I try just () it will never pass the WaitOne i'm not sure what to do here.

```
private static Semaphore _pool;
_pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(),options, drow =>
{
    using (var WCC = new MasterCrawlerClass())
    {
                ActiveThreads++;
                _pool.WaitOne(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Active Thread #: " + ActiveThreads);
                WCC.MasterCrawlBegin(drow);
                Console.WriteLine("Done Crawling a datarow");
                ActiveThreads--;
                _pool.Release();

    }
});
```

Comment: Seeing as you're setting maxdop to 1, what does the use of Parallel.ForEach actually buy you here? The loop body will also probably be running in the ThreadPool, where blocking code is a big no-no. You should also be guarding against concurrent access to ActiveThreads. Can you explain what you're trying to do here? There's probably a better way.

Comment: @spender All i want to be able to do is limit the number of times the Parallel.Foreach actually calls WCC

Comment: Limit to what? At most 3 concurrent crawls?

Comment: @spender yes that would be fine, but i really just want to say int = ; and whatever it is limit to that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are miscontructing the semaphore. It should be `_pool = new Semaphore(3, 3);` Doing that will also eliminate the need to pass in a timeout parameter to `WaitOne()`.

The first parameter is the initial number of requests that may be granted before blocking, so passing 0 means any subsequent calls to `WaitOne()` will immediately block.

Comment: It might just be because I dont understand, but isnt the first Int intial count?  I want to have 0, and then continue until I have 3, and the second int is max, so should it be (0,3)

Comment: @Mike It's the initial count *that may be granted*; setting it to 0 means "you can initially grant 0 requests before blocking", which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: This might not be what I want, in my foreach loop it only goes into one loop regardless if I change it to (3,3) or (4,8) why is that

Comment: @Mike: Because you set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here.

- I suspect there is little reason to throttle concurrency in this situation in the first place.
- You are setting `initialCount` to 0 in the `Semaphore` constructor. `initialCount` is the number of requests that can be granted *right now*.
- You are using the overload of `WaitOne` that accepts a timeout parameter. When the timeout expires `WaitOne` will return regardless of whether a count was taken from the semaphore.
- You are incrementing `ActiveThreads` *before* taking a count from the semaphore. This means that `ActiveThreads` more closely approximates the number of simultaneous worker threads for the `ForEach` operation. It will not tell you how many of those threads are executing `MasterCrawlBegin`.
- The `++` operation on `ActiveThreads` is not thread-safe.
- You set `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` to a value that pretty much eliminates any kind of concurrent processing.

Change your code so that it looks like this.

```
int ActiveThreads = 0;
int ActiveCrawls = 0;
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3, 3); 
Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(), drow => 
  { 
    int x = Interlocked.Increment(ref ActiveThreads);
    Console.WriteLine("Active Thread #: " + x); 
    semaphore.Wait();
    int y = Interlocked.Increment(ref ActiveCrawls);
    Console.WriteLine("Active Crawl #: " + y); 
    try
    {
      using (var WCC = new MasterCrawlerClass()) 
      { 
        WCC.MasterCrawlBegin(drow);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      Interlocked.Decrement(ref ActiveCrawls);
      semaphore.Release();
      Interlocked.Decrement(ref ActiveThreads);
      Console.WriteLine("Done Crawling a datarow"); 
    }
  } 
});
```

And of course you can just set `MaxDegreesOfParallelism = 3` and not worry about all the semaphore stuff.

Comment: Refer to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10116536/158779) here for further analysis of your problem and a reason why I think throttling parallelism is a bad idea in this situation.